# Unity adding to transform moves too far

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a form and I want to shift the inputs/children of the form down to show an error message when needed.

I can loop over the children and I just want to shift then each down 20 pixels which are about the height of the error text but the input moves about 3000 down the x-axis. I am sure it is going to be obvious what I am doing wrong.

```
foreach (Transform child in Form.transform)
{
    Vector3 p = child.position;
    Debug.Log(child.name);
    p.x += 20f;
    child.position = p;
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind, each unity unit is 100 pixels based on default camera setting, so by 20f , your actually moving them 2000 pixels

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative approach:

- in your interface, create a panel or scroll view or whatever container to hold your UI
- add a vertical layout group say if you want to lay items out in a vertical fashion
- add your placeholder control disabled, e.g. a `Text` or whatever
- whenever you want to display an error, enable this control with appropriate content

The layout system will take care of shifting all elements positions for you.

Comment: Did try that but the vertical layout destroys the particular layout I have because it wants to force space out the inputs and text.

Comment: It can be frustrating at times to get it right, don't forget that you can add a layout element to your prefab so it doesn't get affected by the parent layout group.